# ECB - avoid opening new windows

Tags: window, frames, window-splitting

I use Emacs for programming and I have `ECB`; this package works very well for me except with some commands; the problem arises when a command tries to show its result in another window (e.g. `rtags`'s `find-symbol` or `undo-tree`), because in this case instead of splitting the `Edit` window of `ECB` in half and using the two windows (analogously to what happens when NOT using `ECB`) it opens a new frame, which is something that I would like to avoid.

Is there a way to force every command to make the required splits on the `Edit` window instead of opening a new frame?
Right now what I managed to do is to manually change the functions I use the most, substituting the call to `switch-to-buffer-other-window` with `switch-to-buffer`, but it would be crazy to do this with every function.

Comment: There's `display-buffer-alist`, but I'm not sure whether ECB honors it...

Comment: This would indeed be a nice feature. I am using ggtags and it has the same problem.

Comment: ecb advices many standard functions to keep its layout. But what ecb does to the standard behavior is much worse than what the standard behavior does to the ecb layout. Completion is the most critical part for me. It just does not work with the ecb advices activated. You can turn off the advices by `(defun ecb-not-using-layout-advices (&rest args)
  "Do not use the layout advices of ecb."
  (ecb-disable-advices 'ecb-layout-basic-adviced-functions))

(advice-add #'ecb-activate--impl :after #'ecb-not-using-layout-advices)`.